# How to modify an assembly before it is packaged in a XAP?

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task, xap, .net-assembly

I have a MSBuild task that modifies an assembly. At the moment I place the Task in the AfterBuild Target of the project file. Unfortunately this does not work for Silverlight because the XAP is packaged before the afterbuild is fired. The same problem exists for VSIX projects.

So how do I get this scenario to work?

Is there another Target I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need compiled assembly for modification you can change target name on "AfterCompile". In AfterCompile target you will get only the assembly without any additional resources like satellite assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds lot like

[How can I inject a XAML transformation into my build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921629/how-can-i-inject-a-xaml-transformation-into-my-build/4923436#4923436)

I gave a suggestion there that I think would help ya out.  Take a look.  If not, lemme know.